# What syntax is used to describe Kafka data structure in ZooKeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka / Zookeeper and I confused a bit by a syntax that is used to describe Kafka data structure in Zookeeper. For example:

```
Schema:
{ "fields" :
    [ {"name": "version", "type": "int", "doc": "version id"},
      {"name": "partitions",
       "type": {"type": "map",
                "values": {"type": "array", "items": "int", "doc": "a list of replica ids"},
                "doc": "a map from partition id to replica list"},
      }
    ]
}
```

The next sample data from Zookeeper satisfies the schema:

```
{"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[0]}}
```

Why words `fields`, `name`, `type` are not appeared in sample? Why only some of columns and commas are appeared?

My question is where I can read about this syntax?

I will appreciate very much any suggestion.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figure out that this is JSON structure.